# What type of tree is this? (found in a Tokyo Park)

Tags: identification, trees

I'm curious which species of tree this is found in Igusa Mori Park.

[image]

Comment: Is the lumpy green thing in the small picture some kind of fruit, or is it a strangely formed leaf?

Comment: @Stephie It is a seed pod.  They were all over the ground near by and all looked pretty much the same.  Although the pods seemed to turn black quickly after falling out of the tree and the whitish seeds exposed themselves soon after.

Comment: This could be a gingko

Comment: @user33232 certainly *not a Ginko*. The [Ginko biloba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginkgo_biloba) is unique in its leaf shape: the veins fan out from the leaf stem, unlike all other trees where we see a central vein and smaller veins branching out from there. The picture clearly shows the latter pattern. The shape of a Ginko leaf is also super distinct in its fan-shape with a wavy edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seed pod makes me believe that this is a Magnolia. Asymmetrical pods like this occur when they are not wholly pollinated.

See: https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2014/08/01/gall-seed-pod/

Comment: Thanks!  This looks right.  Wikipedia lists 4 species of Magnolia native to Japan.  I guess I can narrow it down once I see the flowers.